# How to use go modules to load sub directory in pulsar

Tags: go, go-modules, apache-pulsar

I am trying to use pulsar go client using go modules but not able to import with the correct version.

Created a go.mod file with pulsar dependency and also added other dependencies, earlier I was using dep and everything was fine. Now I moved to go modules and other packages are fine except pulsar dependency, I am not sure like what i am Missing.

```golang
module sample 
go 1.13 
require  github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go/pulsar v2.4.1
```

require github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go: version "v2.4.1" invalid: unknown revision pulsar-client-go/v2.4.1

Answer (score 0):

The latest release `v2.4.1` is on github.com/apache/pulsar and the line should read:

```
require  github.com/apache/pulsar v2.4.1
```

The module `pulsar-client-go` has no release (tag on github) and an error is reported.
Using `go get github.com/apache/pulsar` for instance should download all required dependencies.

Comment: I tried it but it was not working, What is get after doing a ```go build``` is  ```require (
 github.com/apache/pulsar v2.4.1+incompatible
 github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go v0.0.0-20191027154418-6fb5fd207cfd
)``` which is like the C++ libs got the old version and it starts erroring out. ERROR: ```go: finding github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go latest
# github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go/pulsar
In file included from c_client.go:24:0,```

Comment: Which go version do you use ? Is any value set for GO111MODULE ?

Comment: Verions ```go version go1.13.3 linux/amd64``` , Yes GO11MODULE=yes is enabled i am able to get all the other dependencies only pulsar due to nested structure is having this issue.

Comment: Details of documentation are https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules. GO111MODULE=on (or auto on go1.13). Value "yes" gives unpredictable results.

Comment: Thanks, I tried both parameters for GO111MODULE,  on and auto but still it is getting the same error the submodule  becomes the latest like ```require (
 github.com/apache/pulsar v2.4.1+incompatible
 github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go v0.0.0-20191030143938-7b5693fed89a
)
``` after i do a go build

Comment: This seems intended as no error message displays; go get -u returns a similar log.

Comment: The major problem is after i tried to use modules , all the other libraries work, the root is downloading github.com/apache/pulsar with that tag, then it again downloads github.com/apache/pulsar/pulsar-client-go with the latest version the problem is since it uses C++ , cgo to maintain the dep it is not working.

Comment: Issue https://github.com/golang/go/issues/34165 reports the same problem which will be fixed in the next release go1.14.